# Suma total de una columna

Tags: javascript, jquery, jade

Tengo esta columna de una tabla en `html` la cual necesito hacer una suma total y el resultado insertarlo un un `input` de tipo texto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`td(class='sumTtotal')`  Está es mi td donde queda cada resultado de la dif $

Lo que estaba intentado realizar es sacar el valor de cada td y agregarla a un arreglo para luego sumarlo todo

```
$(function() {
    var arrText = new Array();
    $('.sumaTotal').find("td").map(function() {
        arrText.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(arrText);
});
```

Pero no me trae ninguna información

Esta es la tabla la cual esta en `Jade`

```
 table(id='table-preAjuste' class='table table-striped table-hover table-condensed analisisD')
    thead
      tr
        th='Articulo'
        th='Descripción'
        th='Um'
        th='Ov'
        th='Ubic'
        th='Ubic F'
        th='Teorico'
        th(class='vi1')='Conteo1'
        th(class='vi2')='Conteo2'
        th(class='vi3')='Conteo3'
        th='Dif'
        th='Dif'
        th='Dif $'
        th(class='vi3')='Asignar conteo'
        th='Ajustar'
          input(type="checkbox" id='selectall')
        th='Reversar'

      tbody
      if PreAjuste != undefined
        each PArticulos in PreAjuste
          tr
            td(id='id_articulo' class='iarticulo')= PArticulos.SI_Articulo
            td= PArticulos.SI_Descripcion
            td= PArticulos.SI_UM
            td= PArticulos.SI_OV
            td= PArticulos.SI_Ubicacion
            td= PArticulos.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica
            td= PArticulos.SI_Existencia
            td(class='vi1')= PArticulos.SI_Cantidad
            td(class='vi2')
            td(class='vi3')
            td= PArticulos.SI_Dif
            td(contenteditable='true')
            td(class='sumTtotal')= PArticulos.SI_Dif_Dinero
```

y asi se ve la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Espero que me puedan ayudar, Gracias.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el HTML referente a dicha tabla? Ahora mismo no te podemos dar una respuesta exacta de tu problema.

Comment: No pegues la tabla de Jade, si no el html que te genera la pagina

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el HTML referente a dicha tabla? Ahora mismo no te podemos dar una respuesta exacta de tu problema. X2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas utilizando `val()` que es para los controles del formulario (textarea, checkbox, radio, textbox, select) sobre un `td` que no es un control.

Utiliza `.text()` que obtiene el texto de los elementos html:

```js
var data = [];

$("td.sumTotal").each(function(){
  data.push(parseFloat($(this).text()));
});


var suma = data.reduce(function(a,b){ return a+b; },0);

console.log(data);
console.log(suma);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="sumTotal">5.6</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="sumTotal">5</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="sumTotal">5</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: tu respuesta no le da la solucion a la pregunta solo es un complemento

Comment: `parseInt` o `parseFloat`? Creo que sería mejor mantener los decimales.

Comment: Cierto, no habia notado ese detalle @Dev.Joel

Comment: @Einer Una pregunta, el resultado lo puedo pasar a miles después del reduce?

Comment: Que quieres decir con "pasar a miles"?

Comment: El problema puede resolverse sin utilizar un array. Esta solución consume espacio adicional ya que requiere la creacion de un array del mismo tamaño que la cantidad de filas. Ademas consume mas tiempo, ya que se recorre el array dos veces, al crearlo y al sumarlo.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo de la manera siguiente:

```
$(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $("td.sumaTotal").each(function(){
        sum += parseFloat( $( this ).text() );
    });

    $("#your-input-id").val(sum);
});
```

Comment: `parseInt` o `parseFloat`? Creo que sería mejor mantener los decimales

Comment: @Dev.Joel Editado para usar `parseFloat()` en lugar de `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Tomando como referencia la respuesta anterior, lo podemos adecuar a tu pregunta de esta manera**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var data = [];
$("td.subtotal").each(function(){
  data.push(parseFloat($(this).text()));
});
var suma = data.reduce(function(a,b){ return a+b; },0);
    $("#detalle_total").html(suma);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr>
  <td class="subtotal">-106952.291</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="subtotal">-66225.678</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="subtotal">-993385.17</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="subtotal">-1176545.887</td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="subtotal">-534793.585</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="subtotal">-156381.806</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<br>
<div>Suma total :
<lable id="detalle_total"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Tomar en cuenta que está perdiendo los valores decimales con `parseInt` lo cuál no sería correcto.

Comment: ya lo corregi :D